# Is there something wrong with my Flutter installation?

Tags: flutter, cmd

I'm trying to run `flutter pub get` from the root directory of my flutter project which is at `C:\users\admin\androidstudioprojects\projectname`, but I keep getting the following error:

> flutter is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable
> program or batch file.

However, there are no issues found when I run `flutter doctor` from `C:\flutter`.

These are the paths in my environment variables:

```
C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Scripts\
C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\
C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps
C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\atom\bin
%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps
flutter\bin
C:\Program Files\Git\cmd
C:\Windows\System32
```

Comment: You need the full path to flutter, not just a relative one.

Comment: go to flutter installation folder and copy the full path otherwise command doesn't work

Comment: Correct. I actually needed ```C:\flutter\flutter\bin``` If you add that as an answer, I'll mark it correct.

Answer (score 2):

Please try adding the full path of the bin in the PATH variables that would solve it.